# Why are the <div> borders bleeding through the <ul>?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've recently gotten back into coding, and continuing off where I left, trying to create a mobile-first site for a hypothetical apartment website.

With that being said, I've noticed that bottom border of a different , with the class ".description_section", is visible through the one containing the  element.

The  is within the  tag with the id "sidebar". Not the most aesthecally-pleasing side nav (as fonts is my weak point).

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1szN.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

      <div id="sidebar">

        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Amenities</li>
          <li>Floor Plans</li>
          <li>About Us</li>
        </ul>
  
        
      </div><!--close #sidebar-->

<div class="row" id="big_picture">
        <div class="row" id="social_media">
        <div class="col-4" id="facebook">
         <img src="images/fb.svg">
        </div><!-- close .social_media_icon-->
    
        <div class="col-4" id="twitter">
         <img src="images/twitter.svg">
        </div><!-- close .social_media_icon-->
      
        <div class="col-4" id="google_plus">
          <img src="images/google_plus.svg">
        </div><!-- close .social_media_icon-->
      </div><!--close #social_media-->
      </div><!--close #big_picture-->

<div class="row description_section">
         <hr>
        <h2>Directions</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consectetur tristique tortor feugiat dictum. Duis placerat orci vel massa interdum dapibus eu id risus. Curabitur tempor placerat congue. Curabitur ut augue sit amet arcu volutpat rutrum ut sit amet turpis.</p>

<div class="desc_image" id="one"></div><!--close .desc_image-->
</div><!--.description_section-->
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
  left: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  /*border: 1px solid white;*/
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  
}

#big_picture {
  height: 13.4em;
  background: url("../images/apt_lobby.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.description_section {
  background-color: #1d2f5c;
  color: white;
}

.description_section h2 {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: bold;
}

.description_section p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 1% 5% 5% 5%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#hamburger_menu").click(function() {
    $("#sidebar").toggle(1000);
  });
```

If people would like more code snippets, including the one with id of the  whose borders is bleeding through, please let me know!

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with the code you've posted. Could you add the code for the "Directions" element to your question?

Comment: Okay, so I've added some more code, and the <div> containing the "Directions" is in the class called "description_section", as it is a class that I plan on re-using for other pages. I can also add another picture, a bigger picture of the overall screenshot should it be helpful.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the `hr` in the `.description_section` element. Check through the inspector if it has `position:relative` or `posiiton:absolute`.

Comment: Wow....thanks! All I had to do.......was take out the <hr>.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's because of the

```
position: absolute
```

Try playing around with this and also height of the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

try to make the ul higher z-index

```
ul {
position: absolute;
z-index:9;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).